# Bug in basic recursive program, can anyone see the issue?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I have a program here that keeps summing the digits of a number until I get a single number. For example, given num = 38, the process is like: 3 + 8 = 11, 1 + 1 = 2. Since 2 has only one digit, return it.

The problem is, the value being returned to main is garbage, but just before the value is returned from the function addDigits(), it is the correct one. Can anyone see my bug here? It's driving me crazy. Many thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


int addDigits(int num)
{
    vector <int> nums;

    if (num <10)
    {
        return num;
    }

    int rem, temp = 0;

    while (num > 9)
    {
        temp = num /10;
        rem = num %10;
        nums.push_back(rem);
        num = temp;
    }

    nums.push_back(num);

    int total = nums[0];
    for (int i = 1;  i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        total += nums[i];
    }

    cout<<"total :"<<total<<endl;



    if (total >= 10)
    {
        addDigits(total);
    }

    else
    {
        return total;
    }

}

int main()
{
    int val   = 0;
    int total = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"Enter a number : "<<endl;
        cin>>val;

        total = addDigits(val);

        cout<<total<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Engineer999 Didn't your compiler warn you about not returning anything?

Comment: I don't also don't know why the downvotes?. Do they expect everyone on here to be an expert?  then there would be no need for this forum

Comment: @Engineer999 I didn't downvote myself, but I could imagine those who did did so because this could easily have been solved by running it through a debugger. And/or enabling and reading compiler warnings.

Comment: It's not a forum and it's not a debugging service. I fail to see how this question is ever going to be of assistance to other visitors?

Comment: I think a simpler solution is `return num < 10 ? num : addDigits(num % 10 + addDigits(num / 10));`, but I'll admit my modulus arithmetic is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 9):

You don't return the recursive call:

```
addDigits(total);
//should be
return addDigits(total);
```

You should ensure that you have warnings turned on in your compiler to catch issues like this. GCC, for example, gives this warning:

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I didn't spot it

Comment: @Engineer999 always compile with -Wall -Wextra and fix every warning the compiler throws at you.

Answer (score 3):

`addDigits(total);` - this branch doesn't return anything.